# EOFError on input()

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5, python-3.6

I found this code and I try to use it on python 3 but it doesn't work on geeks IDE

```
list=input('racecar:')

if (list==list[::-1]):
    print ("It is a palindrome")
else:
   print("it is not palindrome")
```

I'm getting :

> list=input('racecar:') EOFError: EOF when reading a line

Comment: firstly don't use `list` as a variable name, it shadows the built-in type `list` secondly did you try to debug this? *Doesn't work* does not fully explain the problem

Comment: Works on my machine. If you're getting an error message, post it. If the program is running but producing unexpected output, post the input, the expected output, and the actual output.

Comment: can you be any more specific? What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Does it throw an error?  Because that code works fine for me. typing out `abba` prints `"It is a palindrome"`, typing in `abbab` prints `"It is not a palindrome"`, as I would have expected.

Comment: Don't use list to store the input string, because list is a built-in type in python. What do you mean by it doesn't work? Are you getting any error or are you getting the wrong output. Please specify the problem clearly.

Comment: im getting     list=input('racecar:')
EOFError: EOF when reading a line

Comment: How are you using Python ?

Comment: What does `python --version` show you?

Comment: i use python 3 on ide geeks to test first

Comment: @user9995353 works fine on geeksforgeeks IDE for me as well. Did you perhaps forget to type something into the input field? Because leaving it blank shows your error, but inputting any sequence of characters works fine and returns expected results.

Answer (score 1):

`EOFError: EOF when reading line` can happen during `input` call only if `stdin` is not available or got closed abruptly during the call

Since you mentioned that you are using it from `geeks IDE` I assume that it doesn't have `stdin` redirected for user input

Please try running the code interactively on a terminal using the cmd `python <file>`

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `input` for accepting user input, but may not be providing it to your script.

Instead, try setting your values directly before trying to accept user input.

```
test_values = [
    "non-palindrome",
    "123321",
]

def palindrometest(s):
    return s == s[::-1]

for value in test_values:
    if palindrometest(value):
        print("{} is a palindrome".format(value))
    else:
        print("{} is not a palindrome".format(value))
```

Once you have this working, try `input` in a script by itself to get a good feeling about how it works.

```
s = input("please provide a value: ")
print("user provided '{}'!".format(s))
```